# GUI to open a zlib file

Tags: user-interface, zlib, deflate

I am looking for  simple GUI or software to open (deflate) a zlib compressed file ?
I am not a programmer (well - php does not count) and I just need to open this ONE file and deflate it . all i can find on the net are DLL libraries .

How can a similar file be uncompressed / deflated ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I have already tried 7-zip. But I should have been more specific in my question. I have a file, which I know is using the zlib because I opened it in hex . but the file itself has NO surfix . I actually believe it is a file created with spoon virtual environment. now I just want to "uncompress" it - but all attempts with 7-zip fails. I gave it a surfix lik .gz .z .gzip .zip - but It all comes back to the same error - file not recognized.

Comment: Can someone add some context on this answer?  krembo99 mentioned it did not work for him but has accepted this answer?  Did you find a way to make 7-zip work?